# 2d game collision detection using displacement vectors

Tags: math, collision-detection, intersection

I am trying to implement a collision detection algorithm for my game that uses 2D coordinates (x, y) and quads (rectangles). I am terrible at maths, and prior to making this post I wandered through solutions on stackoverflow, which have left me even more confused as they were stacked with comments saying this doesn't work for this case, or there's a better algorithm than this one, etc...

I did manage to implement a simple AABB collision detection and resolution algorithm in the beginning but later on realized the algorithm doesn't detect cases when the object's speed is high enough for it to phase through objects.

My current thought process was to grab the old position vertices (`oldTL`, `oldTR`, `oldBL`, `oldBR`) and new position vertices (`newTL`, `newTR`, `newBL`, `newBR`) of the object, create 4 line segments represented by two points `(old), (new)` for each pair of vertices, and find out if they intersect any edges on any objects.

I'm very lost and would appreciate any help or feedback I could get...

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach, what isn't working?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find intersections between two line segments. I did come across solutions that used substitution, but how do you do substitution in programming?